# PHP str_replace and regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I am trying by the `preg_replace` function to remove the following part of the text string (`/ page / * /`), where `*` is any number:

```
/ page / 5 /
/ page / 10 /
/ page / 1 /

...
```

This code is wrong but so that you understand what I want to do

```
str_replace ('/ page / * /', '', $ string);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You said you're trying `preg_replace()`, but your code use `str_replace()`.

Comment: It seems like you need to read a tutorial on regular expressions. `\d+` is how you match a number, not `*`.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, `\d` matches a digit, so `\d+` matches a number with any number of digits.

When using `preg_replace()`, you have to put delimiters around the regular expression.

```
$string = preg_replace('#/ page / \d+ /#', '', $string);
```

Comment: Your help was very useful, I am going to study a little more about regex but I have already solved it.